# Is There any way to get App info from api key and api secret on facebook

Tags: facebook

Is There any way to get App info from api key and api secret on facebook, i want to get all info about my app and want to save in DB.

Site URL,
Contact Email,
Support Email,
Daily New Users,
Daily Active Users,
Daily Canvas Visitors

Comment: can you be more specific? What info do you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this information is available on the facebook developer app. The insights data you can get from the insights graph api.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

Comment: I don't want to login I want to fetch app info from server side code with the help of api key and secret, I don't have access token.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin explains how to retrieve an app-specific access token using the Application ID and secret. You can use this token to retrieve your application's Insights data.